# How to pin certificate.pem and private_key.pem files to sign http request in Swift

Tags: swift, ssl, certificate, alamofire, certificate-pinning

I have this two files (**certificate.pem** and **private_key.pem**) which provided me by the API that I use. I need to use this files to sign my http request in Swift project.

I'm able to do it with Postman. I added certificate.pem as CRT file and private_key.pem as KEY file in Add Client Certificate tab of Postman. And when I send PUT request with headers and parameters on Postman, I'm getting success message from the web server.

But when I tried all of these things in Xcode with Swift3 and Alamofire, I'm always getting error message. Could you help me how to pin this PEM files to http request please?

Comment: are you trying SSL pining with certificates?

Comment: Yes I guess so :)

Comment: was this for the Teller or Plaid API ?

Comment: Yes @FernandoB, it was for Teller API... It's good to see that someone facing similar problems 2 years laters :)

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire does not support **PEM** files directly. You need to convert them first to **DER** files which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14484363/1342462). Then, you need to add your new **DER** file(s) to your app target. Finally, you follow the directions in the [Security](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#security) section of the README to enable a server trust policy.

```
let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
    "test.example.com": .pinCertificates(
        certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificates(),
        validateCertificateChain: true,
        validateHost: true
    ),
    "insecure.expired-apis.com": .disableEvaluation
]

let sessionManager = SessionManager(
    serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(
        policies: serverTrustPolicies
    )
)
```

The `ServerTrustPolicy.certificates()` call can be found [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/ServerTrustPolicy.swift#L125-L147) which loads all the data from the **CER** and **DER** files from the bundle and uses them for pinning.

Hopefully that helps gets you going.

Comment: Actually, I've try to do this. But as far as I understand, due to use of two certificate(I mean, certificate and private_key), I'm getting trouble. @cnoon

Comment: Also I'm getting this error.
CredStore - copyIdentPrefs - Error copying Identity cred.  Error=-25300, query={
    class = idnt;
    labl = "https://api.teller.io:443/";
    "r_Ref" = 1;
}