# How can these PEM files (including chain) be converted to KEY and CRT files?

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

There is a very similar question here that but as far as I can tell it deals with one input PEM file whereas I have three, one of which is a chain file.

[Convert .pem to .crt and .key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732826/convert-pem-to-crt-and-key)

I have these three files generated by a LetsEncrypt helper program (win-acme).

```
foo.bar.co.uk-chain.pem
foo.bar.co.uk-crt.pem
foo.bar.co.uk-key.pem
```

What commands should I run in `openssl` (or otherwise) to generate two files in the form of `foo.bar.co.uk.key` and `foo.bar.co.uk.crt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extensions in filenames do not matter.

`foo.bar.co.uk-key.pem` is `foo.bar.co.uk.key` and `foo.bar.co.uk.crt` is either just `foo.bar.co.uk-crt.pem` or the concatenation of `foo.bar.co.uk-crt.pem` and `foo.bar.co.uk-chain.pem` depending on where/how it is used.

PEM is just the name of the format to encode either the certificate or the key.

But again (since it is a very widespread false assumption): the filenames, including their extensions, do not matter at all. You can call your file `foo.bar` and it will work the same way, as long as the **content** is right.

Comment: Oh, that makes a lot of sense now. Thanks for the explanation.