# What converts Google Play Console certificate to PEM. format?

Tags: formatting, certificate, pem, google-play-console

I need to convert my Google Play app's certificate to PEM. format. Forgive me if this is a stupid question, but I have no idea how to do this. Any advice on what I can use to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was going to write my own answer, but https://stackoverflow.com/a/38408666/4265103 is much more detailed. Copied here for convenience: `openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.der -out certificate.pem`

Comment: I tried. OpenSSL can't run on this machine for some reason.

Comment: Can you run keytool?

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to figure this out, but I finally used Keystore Explorer. It even converts the certificate into the correct format for the Google Play Console.

[KeyStore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/)