# Aurora serverless Postgresql fails to connect via TLS/SSL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, ssl, psql, aws-aurora-serverless

I am trying to connect to a serverless Aurora serverless PostGRESQL RDS instance with SSL, but in vain.

My RDS lies on a private subnet group (2 private subnets) and I am trying to connect from an EC2 instance lying in public subnet.

What works:

```
psql -h "mydb.cluster-cyjoviss5z9y.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com" -p 5432 -d "dbname=mydb user=postgres password=NVMXeyQRXIzW50xx"
psql (9.2.24, server 10.7)
WARNING: psql version 9.2, server version 10.0.
         Some psql features might not work.
SSL connection (cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.

mydb=
```

However, this doesn't work:
psql -h "mydb.cluster-cyjoviss5z9y.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com" -p 5432 -d "dbname=mydb user=postgres password=NVMXeyQRXIzW50xx sslmode=verify-ca"

Error:
*psql: root certificate file "/home/ec2-user/.postgresql/root.crt" does not exist*

OR
*psql: SSL error: certificate verify failed*

The same above command with sudo works, but when I verify the connection it still says:

```
mydb=> select ssl_is_used();
 ssl_is_used
-------------
 f
(1 row)
```

So I downloaded the root certificate from [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/rds-downloads/rds-ca-2019-root.pem), as suggested in [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Security.html#AuroraPostgreSQL.Security.SSL) page. It even mentions that AWS Serverless instances don't require the root certificate to be downloaded.

I converted the PEM file into CRT using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14484363/1322460). I tried giving the root.crt file with 777 and 600 permissions, both didn't help.

Any hints on what can possibly go wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently AWS still doesn't support SSL connections for Postgres Aurora databases yet!