# Convert plain text RSA public key into the file extension supported by certificate store on windows

Tags: openssl, certificate, rsa, public-key-encryption

I have a plain text public key coming from client. Now we don't want to save that public key as it is in the code/config, we want to create certificate out of it so that we can install it in the certificate store which is easy to maintain in case of the change in the public key. (I tried converting it to the CER, DER, CRT using OPENSSL but it is not working)

This is the public key I have:

MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAl1nIJ9A6onY2dbNUY0I6OE7971BtDn+lpSb8Ce0+0mJfwldjYnWwoeYekDnkWMMzvQoDlrjKYW7WOSW22oZLJoJMlnSSGQtPp8afEIksjOiGSK+UaRKdDJVLfmqwEzGLndVnhu6dDxcIGAtzz7y38dcmH1rKlmZ36pqWBVPNcqQSSDt3E9F26st9ftNjTamw/hChGBGSJwpNVgtuNNf1W+Ts3RXhQpxBkEcYLz3rZe2F35rjsVi8iEEgXa18mzcKOgAAP9KipCegQfR80CoDAAdUx4g630QMHKn4sETWu3ztu3beWIoyLzgEZgQUn83bTHqGKQdAmdibk9bj7MI5jwIDAQAB

[Convert .pem to .crt and .key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732826/convert-pem-to-crt-and-key)

Comment: This is a Base64 encoded public ASN.1/DER key in X.509/SPKI format. You can't make it a certificate just by changing the file extension. A certificate is more than a public key, see [X.509](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509).

Comment: Thank you 
@Topaco.. If client will give us CSR(Certificate signing request), can we create the certificate out of it?

Comment: A CSR is used to request a certificate from a CA, see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request). Also, the CSR can be used to create a self-signed certificate, which is probably what you are interested in, see e.g. [here](https://www.baeldung.com/openssl-self-signed-cert).